# Left eigenvector for eigenvalue < 1 for a square stochastic matrix: coordinates of eigenvector sum to zero.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices

If $v$ is a left eigenvector of stochastic matrix $P$ with $vP = \lambda v$ for $\lambda <1$, can you show that $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} v_{i} = 0$. You can assume that $v$ is normalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* Consider $vPe$ where $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$.

Comment: Thanks, I see how this works relying on orthogonality of left and right eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues.